# Recurrence relation (not solvable by the master theorem)

Tags: time-complexity

Consider the following recursion:
$\begin{cases}
T(n) = 2T(\frac{n}{2}) + \frac{n}{\log n} &n > 1 \\
         O(1) &n = 1
\end{cases}$.

The master theorem doesn't work, as the exponent of $\log n$ is negative. So I tried unfolding the relation and finally got the equation:
$T(n) = n[1 + \frac{1}{\log(\frac{n}{2})} + \frac{1}{\log(\frac{n}{4})} + ... + \frac{1}{\log(2)}]$.

I do not know how to simplify (inequalities to use???) from here. A trivial method would be to assume that all reciprocal of the log terms are $< \frac{1}{\log(2)}$, and since there are $\log n$ terms, the summation of all the reciprocal-log terms is $< \frac{\log n }{\log(2)} = \log_2 n$, which gives $T(n) = O(n \log n)$. However this is a very poor approximation, as by the master theorem we can check that the time complexity for the recursive relation $T(n) = 2T(\frac{n}{2}) + n$ is $O(n \log n)$. Can someone find a tighter correct upper bound?

Comment: Check the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_(analysis_of_algorithms)).

Comment: Note that it's the master theorem (like a master key), not Master's theorem (named after some Professor Master).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_(analysis_of_algorithms)) has a slight extension of the master theorem which covers your case: case 2b [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_(analysis_of_algorithms)#Generic_form).
For the recurrence $T(n)=aT(n/b)+f(n)$ where $f(n)=\Theta(n^{\log_b a}/\log n)$, it gives $T(n)=n^{\log_b a}\log\log n$.